# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch' while installing torch_sparse

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I want to upload my app using Streamlit cloud.

Here is the info and my `requirements.txt` in github:

```
**Collecting torch==1.8.1

  Downloading torch-1.8.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (804.1 MB)

     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 804.1/804.1 MB 147.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00[2023-02-23 12:32:59.564581] 

Collecting matplotlib==3.5.2

  Downloading matplotlib-3.5.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.2 MB)

     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 11.2/11.2 MB 90.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00

Collecting translate==3.6.1
Collecting torch_sparse==0.6.16
  Downloading torch_sparse-0.6.16.tar.gz (208 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 208.2/208.2 KB 285.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00[2023-02-23 03:52:24.740968] 
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-6ook3r5m/torch-sparse_a4c09b3da42046a5a246b2ccd6433d71/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
          import torch
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

My `requirements.txt`:

```
torch==1.8.1
matplotlib==3.5.2
translate==3.6.1
numpy==1.21.6
pandas==1.3.5
streamlit==1.15.1
plotly==5.11.0
scipy==1.7.3
networkx==2.6.3
rdkit==2022.9.2
requests==2.28.1
Pillow==9.4.0
scikit_learn==1.2.1
torch_sparse==0.6.16
torch_geometric==2.1.0.post1**`
```

I tried to update `pip` and `setuptools` and it does not solve the problem.From the log, streamlit cloud installed torch first and then torch-sparse. I don't know what to do.

Comment: torch-sparse is having a dependency with torch. So you need to install torch first

Answer (score 1):

You can install them by writing this inside the `requirements.txt`:

```
-f data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.13.0+cu116.html torch-sparse
-f data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.13.0+cu116.html torch-scatter
```

See the [README.md](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_sparse#pytorch-113) of the pytorch_sparse repository.

---

An alternative would be to do the installation sequentially:

```bash
pip install torch==1.8.1
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

---

There currently is an [open issue](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_sparse/issues/156) on the pytorch_sparse GitHub repository about this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. My local computer has installed pytorch and torch sparse. The problem I describe occurs when streamlit cloud automatically reads requirements.txt and performs the installation based on the content. According to the log, streamlit did install torch before torch-sparse

Comment: Sadly, `Collecting torch==1.8.1` does not mean that torch has been installed, just retrieved. Since they are inside the same `requirements.txt` file, by doing `pip install -r requirements.txt` will not install them one after the other. To do so, you need to do 2 sequential commands.

Comment: Thank you ,and I got it 。 But I can't execute my own commands in the streamlint cloud. The process of packaging the whole program is to connect the streamlint cloud with my github, and then enter the project URL. The rest of the work will be automatically completed by streamlint cloud, and I can't participate in it. So I don't understand how I should do it according to your instructions

Comment: Thank you ! Now I know how to fix it. I should use :-f data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.13.0+cu116.html torch-sparse -f data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.13.0+cu116.html torch-scatter  in my requirements.txt,instead of pip them!

Comment: I updated the answer with your solution